# Docker bridge not showing - is it optional or incorrectly configured?

Tags: networking, docker

I've got a bridge named `docker0`. e.g. `brctl show`

```
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
docker0     8000.0242d342ede7   no      vethfb31a5f
```

however if I run `docker inspect net2` (where `net2` is the name of my container) I get

```
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
```

i.e. an empty bridge name.

From within the container I can ping the internet so clearly networking is working. Is this an optional setting or is it incorrectly configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct. The part you care about is further down, in the "Networks" key:

```
        "Networks": {
            "internal": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": [
                    "90fd1b2a3c56"
                ],
                "NetworkID": "ba6ad6496e0c99dcec8a9386679a9b3982c165e70a7fe3b9d5a19060cff66a12",
                "EndpointID": "653ce3ac54a2b788c4aa2d5457f92d4c924a96bb4cf90d01dd670e44dab7bf5a",
                "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.18.0.2",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02"
            }
        }
```

This shows the docker network to which the container is connected.  The bridge device name isn't available, but can be computed from the given network ID.  See that in `brctl show`:

```
# brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br-ba6ad6496e0c     8000.0242cb80bfd8   no      
docker0     8000.0242fb972d2e   no      
virbr0      8000.feaa3d0e632c   yes     tap0
```

I can see `br-ba6ad6496e0c`, which you will note matches the beginning of the network id for the "internal" network to which I had attached my container.